# set a layer to be invisible in cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

my scene has 2 layers, game,and buttons, with :

```
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    mainScene *layer = [mainScene node];
    buttons *layer2=[buttons node];
    layer.tag=30;
    layer2.tag=40;
    [scene addChild:layer2 z:1];
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

then i am trying to make him invisible when touch on screen with :

```
[[self getChildByTag:40] setVisible:NO];
```

nothing is happen.

what am i doing wrong ?

thanks a lot .

Comment: thanks . touch code is regular,and is happening because i log it, its :  -(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event . the getChildByTag is a big class which i cant put here, but it DOES returns nil when i log it, and i cant figure why .

Comment: Maybe this thread will help: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/12120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scene contains the layer, not `self`, so you need to call `[[[self parent] getChildByTag:40] setVisible:NO];`